How to forward traffic from one port to another on the one device?
On Linux, specifically a Debian distro:
How can I forward traffic from one port to another, all on the same device, before any actual routing occurs?
(For example, all traffic inbound to port 80 on device A gets forwarded to port 8080 also on device A.)
This seems like a simple question, but I can’t find an answer even after researching.
iptables is usually what I use for such networking setups, but there doesn’t appear to be any flags to handle this. Maybe iptables isn’t the right tool?

What you could probably do for port forwarding on the same device is using iptables with the nat table and the PREROUTING chain. Then you can use a REDIRECT target that is specifically designed for this as it will modify the destination port of incoming packets before routing decisions are made.
Try:
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
Using PREROUTING will allow you to alter packets before the routing process.

Thanks- I will try this!

Hey, just tested this out, but it seems that the packets that should be forwarded are being sent back and not forwarded- it's not because there's nothing listening at the forward-ee port, they aren't even reaching it in the first place. Although when checking the current iptables rule chains, apparently it is a valid rule. Do you know why this might be? All good if not.

Maybe I wasn't clear... when I tested this I didn't receive traffic from my network card/Ethernet cable, but instead I Telnet-ed from my machine in the first place as well. Does --preroute also achieve the same function if the connection is internal, too?

OK, sorry to keep spamming you with comments- it turns out I hand a brain-fart as they say, and was using --preroute when I should have been using --OUTPUT. But your answer still applies.

@security_paranoid Glad it worked :) I was asleep when you were commenting, no worries. Yes, the OUTPUT parameter does this locally.
